# Xcode 6 - Archive Sumbmission failed with errors

Tags: ios, titanium, xcode6

I'm getting "Archive Submission Failed with Errors" and I have ran out of ideas on how to upload my app to the App Store successfully. Note that this isn't a new app. I'm just uploading a new version and this is the first time I've ever gotten these errors.
See link for screenshot: http://postimg.org/image/hesdsr167/

Using:

1. Xcode 6.1
2. OSX Yosemite
3. Application Loader 3.0
4. Titanium SDK 3.4.1

Have tried these but none of them helped:

1. Opened all the ports and IP Addresses
2. Used Wireless Hotspots, Ethernet and Wifi
3. Took down firewalls
4. Searched around the Apple Developer Member Center for anything I needed to do
5. I googled

I just need to know at least one of these:

1. A temporary or permanent solution
2. A workaround
3. What causes this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `telnet sgr203.apple.com 44001` to make sure if this issue from XCode or your MAC.
if this issue from your mac try to use VPN may help.
If telnet worked, try to remove XCode cache.

Comment: Thank you so much for this help! Because of this, we realized that my Mac Display was connected to the Ethernet at the same time the MacBook Air was connected a Wifi. So we unhooked the Ethernet from the Display and we uploaded just via Wifi and it worked!